# Is Darth Sidious human or alien?

Tags: star-wars, darth-sidious

I’ve always assumed that Darth Sidious / Palpatine was a human (for the context of this I mean the same as Han, Luke, Leia, etc.) however seeing [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/165405/4295) made me doubt and I don’t think I’ve seen that actually stated.

Is there any reference in canon as to whether Palpatine is a human or an alien?

Comment: @Raj - I think this is what you're looking for; https://i.stack.imgur.com/AsiKa.png

Comment: @Raj - Or this page; https://web.archive.org/web/20131230141038/http://starwars.com/explore/encyclopedia/characters/palpatine/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Human

The [current starwars.com Databank](https://www.starwars.com/databank/emperor-palpatine-darth-sidious) and [old starwars.com Encyclopedia](https://web.archive.org/web/20131230141038/http://starwars.com/explore/encyclopedia/characters/palpatine/) list him as human:

[image]

[image]

Additionally, he was the senator from [Naboo](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Naboo), which is populated by humans and Gungans (and he's obviously not a Gungan). While it's possible that a non-human  and non-Gungan could live on Naboo and become its senator, it is unlikely.

Moreover, Palpatine is

> Rey's ancestor

and she is also human.

Finally, the [Galactic Empire had some xenophobic policies](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Galactic_Empire#Xenophobia), a fact which would be hard to square with a non-human Emperor.

Comment: Palpatine is not Rey's grandfather, His clone is her father.

Comment: @Valorum Technically, correct, but functionally he's the "father" of her father, i.e. grandfather. In any case, I've tweaked the wording.